# validation failure for TrackRequest Error:cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '1' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration

Tags: fedex

Am trying to integrate the Fedex shipping API with my website. For this am using SOAP + XML features. But am getting an error that "SOAP-ENV:ServerFaultUnrecoverableClientErrorSchemaErrorvalidation failure for TrackRequest Error:cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration". 
Anyone can help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the SOAP/XML request you're sending follows an invalid schema, e.g. contains invalid elements or wrong ordering. To further debug this, please post the full API request & response.

I'm working for a company called [Shippo](https://goshippo.com). You can use our API to connect with FedEx via client libraries in all major programming languages - maybe that's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are using an invalid value for an element - an acceptable list of values is already provided in an enumeration in the WSDL.

Example of the restriction:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ImageId">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="IMAGE_1"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="IMAGE_2"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="IMAGE_3"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="IMAGE_4"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="IMAGE_5"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The above means that I can only send `ImageId` as `IMAGE_1`, `IMAGE_2` up to `IMAGE_5`. Anything beyond that would throw the error you mentioned.